# dynamic memory allocation to create array of objects using constructor with arguments c++

Tags: c++

How can I allocate an array of objects using a constructor that takes an argument?

I don't even know if I can?
Or do I just have to create another class method to initialize the objects?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Animal {
    string name;
public:
    Animal(){}
    Animal(string name) : name(name) {};
    virtual ~Animal(){}
    Animal(const Animal &other) : name(other.name) {}
    void toSpeak() const { cout << "My name is " << name << endl; }
};

Animal *createAnimal(){
    Animal *a = new Animal("cat");
    return a;
}

int main() {
    Animal *cat = createAnimal();
    cat->toSpeak();
    delete cat;

    cout << "--------------------------"<<endl;
    Animal *pcat = new Animal[5]();

    delete [] pcat;
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way you'd do it for static arrays:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Animal {
 private:
  std::string name;

 public:
  Animal() = default;
  Animal(std::string name) : name(std::move(name)){}
  virtual ~Animal() = default;
  Animal(const Animal &other) : name(other.name){}
  void toSpeak() const { std::cout << "My name is " << name << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
  using namespace std::literals;
  Animal *pcat = new Animal[5]{"Cat1"s, "Cat2"s, "Cat3"s, "Cat4"s, "Cat5"s};

  delete[] pcat;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you . What the "s" for??

Comment: @RoninZeroo [`operator""s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator""s) is a [user-defined literal suffix](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) that tells the compiler to treat a string literal like `"Cat1"s` as a `std::string` object instead of as a `const char[]` array